# Quick help to optimized query

Tags: sql-server

Quick help to optimized query. I have below query which is running very slow

```
Select
P.*
from
dbo.Parent P
where
exists
(
Select 1
From
dbo.Child C
Where
1 = 1
and C.ColumnName1 = case when @p_ParameterValue is null then C.ColumnName1 else   P.ColumnName1 end
and C.ColumnName2 = isnull(@p_ParameterValue,C.ColumnName2)
)
```

It happens when we have value for parameter. When i try to normalize it. It works really.
I have around 60K records in Parent and for each Column1 i have records in Child.
ColumnName1 and ColumnName2 are clustered index on Child.

```
Select
P.*
from
dbo.Parent P
where
exists
(
Select 1
From
dbo.Child C
Where
1 = 1
and C.ColumnName1 = P.ColumnName1
and C.ColumnName2 = @p_ParameterValue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the conditions in WHERE to be [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/3186160)

```
Select P.*
from dbo.Parent P
where exists
(
  Select 1
  From dbo.Child C
  Where 1 = 1
  and (@p_ParameterValue is null OR C.ColumnName1 = P.ColumnName1)
  and (@p_ParameterValue is null OR C.ColumnName2 = @p_ParameterValue)
)
```

Comment: Thanks TomT for solution. I will try today and update you about performance.